# as3 - TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-builder, flash-cs5, flash-cs4

i have duplicated an object to use it in another frame (the object uses [Greensock](http://www.greensock.com/) to scroll the X axis and i used a function (onMove(evt:MouseEvent)) but when i move my mouse this error comes up in the output tab `TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at Main_fla::mainContianer_1/onMove()` and when i press one of the buttons to enter the new object this error comes up `TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at com.greensock::TweenLite/init()
    at com.greensock::TweenLite/renderTime()
    at com.greensock.core::SimpleTimeline/renderTime()
    at com.greensock::TweenLite$/updateAll()` and the old object comes up

here is the actions of my old one

```
import com.greensock.TweenLite;
import com.greensock.easing.Back;
import com.greensock.easing.Elastic;
import com.greensock.plugins.TweenPlugin;
import com.greensock.plugins.BlurFilterPlugin;

var panelContainer:Sprite = new Sprite;
addChild(panelContainer);

for(var i:Number=0;i<3; i++) {

    var projectPanel:ProjectPanel = new ProjectPanel;
    projectPanel.x = i*(projectPanel.width+10);
    panelContainer.addChild(projectPanel);

    projectPanel.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);

}

function onClick(evt:MouseEvent):void {

    TweenLite.to(panelContainer, 0.5, {y:stage.stageHeight, ease:Back.easeIn});
    MovieClip(this.parent).addFullPanel(Number(evt.currentTarget.name));

}

function slideUp():void {

    TweenLite.to(panelContainer, 0.5, {y:0, ease:Back.easeOut});

}

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onMove);

function onMove(evt:MouseEvent):void {

    if(MovieClip(this.parent).fullProjectPanelUp==false){
    TweenLite.to(panelContainer,0.3, {x:-        (stage.mouseX/1225)*panelContainer.width+stage.stageWidth/2.65});
    }

}

stop();
```

and the new one's actions :

```
import com.greensock.TweenLite;
import com.greensock.easing.Back;
import com.greensock.easing.Elastic;
import com.greensock.plugins.TweenPlugin;
import com.greensock.plugins.BlurFilterPlugin;

var lessonContainer:Sprite = new Sprite;
addChild(lessonContainer);

for(var p:Number=0;p<8; p++) {

    var lessonPanel:LessonPanel = new LessonPanel;
    lessonPanel.x = p*(lessonPanel.width+10);
    lessonContainer.addChild(lessonPanel);

    lessonPanel.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);

}

function onClickLesson(evt:MouseEvent):void {

    TweenLite.to(lessonContainer, 0.5, {y:stage.stageHeight, ease:Back.easeIn});
    MovieClip(this.parent).addfullLessonPanel(Number(evt.currentTarget.name));

}

function slideLessonUp():void {

    TweenLite.to(lessonContainer, 0.5, {y:0, ease:Back.easeOut});

}

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onMove);

function onLessonMove(evt:MouseEvent):void {

    if(MovieClip(this.parent).fullLessonPanelUp==false){
    TweenLite.to(lessonContainer,0.3, {x:-(stage.mouseX/1225)*lessonContainer.width+stage.stageWidth/2.65});
    }

}

stop();
```

and here is the [Project Files](http://www.mediafire.com/?vk0s30tdl361v7s) if u need them

Comment: You use MovieClip(this.parent) all over the place yet you do not have the code inside a class. So let me ask you what is "this.parent" referring to?

Comment: how can i make refer to fullLessonPanel ?!!

Comment: @The_asMan or is there any other way to link it to the "fullLessonPanel" ?!!

Comment: I don't even know what "fullLessonPanel" is. If it is a movieClip then use the instance name.

Answer (score 0):

If the FrameLabelPlugin wasn't activated, TweenLite would act as though you were trying to literally tween the mc.frameLabel property (and there is no such thing).

Activating a plugin requires a single line of code and you only need to do it ONCE in your application, so it's pretty easy. Simply pass an Array containing the names of all the plugins you'd like to activate to the TweenPlugin.activate() method, like this:

```
import com.greensock.plugins.*;
TweenPlugin.activate([FrameLabelPlugin, ColorTransformPlugin]);
```